# How Come I don't get a compile error when i initialize an instance variable in an interface in java

Tags: java, interface

So here is the code for the interface. I searched up on the internet whether you could have an instance variable in an interface and I found out you couldn't but when I tried to initialize an instance variable in an interface I got no compile time error.

```
public interface hgf {
    public void eat();
    int x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps u can try removing the assignment and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the variable x which you think is an instance variable is actually a constant. Interfaces define variables with static final by default even when you don't see it. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks that helps alot